# Linux - Blender UI elements too small

Tags: customization

I am using Blender 2.79b on the LXDE desktop on Debian Linux Stretch. My hardware is an old Core 2 Duo Mac Mini, and I'm using a high-resolution monitor (a TV) by VGA. The UI elements are a tad too small, and Virtual Pixel Mode is not available in the user preferences for some reason. Is there another way to make the UI elements bigger, or a way to enable the missing Virtual Pixel Mode? I should note that the Blender I am using came from Debian's repos as opposed to downloading it straight from Blender's site, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Maybe try an official, daily build (I don't know what version Debian's repos provide..)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution on my own. Turns out that there's a "display scaling" option now that wasn't there in earlier versions of Blender.

[image: Display Scaling option]